# Windows displaying boot information instead of booting

Tags: windows, boot

I recently upgraded to Windows 10, but after a few days my system fails to boot up.
It shows general information about my PC like CPU CLOCK, CPU ID, DRAM at Bank(s), etc.

Here is a photograph of the screen:
[image]
How can I resolve this?

Comment: This may not really help you, but, FYI, that doesn't look like something Windows would display.  That looks like something your computer (possibly the BIOS) would display if it can't load the operating system.  It might help if you posted a little bit more information about your computer itself (e.g., brand, model, how old it is, etc...).

Comment: This is the BIOS "self test" screen. What happens after this screen?

Comment: See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Duplicate of [System Information displayed instead of booting up](http://superuser.com/q/957226)

Comment: It is 6 years old....gigabyte motherboard dual core cpu